# Resize reportlab.platypus.Paragraph flowable?

Tags: python, reportlab, platypus

I've got the following code that attempts to resize the font size of a reportlab Platypus flowable's text until it fits into the available height I have given it. But I'm finding that the Paragraph flowable is not saving its style.fontSize attribute in each loop of the recursion, and python baulks with an infinite recursion.

```
def fits_space(w,h,aW,aH,p):
    """
    Determines if inputted text fits in the space given for a paragraph
    and if it doesn't, reduces the font-size until it does.

    """
    if w<=aW and h<=aH:
        # return font size to apply it to the para again
        print "final font_size: %d" % p.style.fontSize
        return p # now render the paragraph in the doctemplate
    else: 
        p.style.fontSize -= 1
        w,h = p.wrap(aW, aH)
        fits_space(w,h,aW,aH,p)

def renderPage(name, text):
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate("%s.pdf" % name)
    parts = []
    style = ParagraphStyle(name='fancy')
    style.fontSize = 150
    p = Paragraph(text, style)
    aW = PAGE_WIDTH-4*inch  # available width and height 
    aH = PAGE_HEIGHT-4*inch 
    w,h = p.wrap(aW, aH) # find required space
    p = fits_space(w,h,aW,aH,p) # recursively fit the font size to the text
    parts.append(p)
    doc.build(parts)
```

Can anyone let me know why - in the fits_space() function, in the else clause, when I call p.wrap(aW, aH), the outputted value is the same as before I decremented the paragraph's fontSize by 1? Surely the wrapped height should be less if I reduce the font size?

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

**UPDATE**
Nitzie's code below *almost worked* just needed to add a resizer to the style.leading too in my case:

```
def shrink_font_size(aW, aH, text, style):
    """Shrinks font size by using pdfmetrics to calculate the height
    of a paragraph, given the font name, size, and available width."""
    def break_lines(text, aW):
        # simpleSplit calculates how reportlab will break up the lines for
        # display in a paragraph, by using width/fontsize.
        return simpleSplit(text, style.fontName, style.fontSize, aW)

    def line_wrap(lines, style):
        # Get overall width of text by getting stringWidth of longest line
        width = stringWidth(max(lines), style.fontName, style.fontSize)
        # Paragraph height can be calculated via line spacing and number of lines.
        height = style.leading * len(lines)
        return width, height

    lines = break_lines(text, aW)
    width, height = line_wrap(lines, style)

    while height > aH or width > aW:
        style.fontSize -= 1
        style.leading -= 1 # do this if you're leading is based on the fontSize
        lines = break_lines(text, aW)
        width, height = line_wrap(lines, style)
```

TIA

Comment: Where do the `PAGE_WIDTH` and `PAGE_HEIGHT` variables come from?

Comment: I fixed a similar problem with ``KeepInFrame``.  I thought I would leave a link to the answer in case anyone stumbles on this question like I did. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014573/reportlab-how-to-auto-resize-text-to-fit-block/21294357#21294357

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason, `p.wrap` does not seem to truly recalculate height/width once you've changed the fontsize after calling it once already.

I was able to get a working version by calculating font size based on ReportLab's `stringWidth` and `splitLines` methods. Although this means it is no longer recursive:

```
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate
from reportlab.lib.styles import ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph
from reportlab.lib.utils import simpleSplit
from reportlab.pdfbase.pdfmetrics import stringWidth

def shrink_font_size(aW, aH, text, style):
    """Shrinks font size by using pdfmetrics to calculate the height
    of a paragraph, given the font name, size, and available width."""
    def break_lines(text, aW):
        # simpleSplit calculates how reportlab will break up the lines for
        # display in a paragraph, by using width/fontsize.
        return simpleSplit(text, style.fontName, style.fontSize, aW)

    def line_wrap(lines, style):
        # Get overall width of text by getting stringWidth of longest line
        width = stringWidth(max(lines), style.fontName, style.fontSize)
        # Paragraph height can be calculated via line spacing and number of lines.
        height = style.leading * len(lines)
        return width, height

    lines = break_lines(text, aW)
    width, height = line_wrap(lines, style)

    while height > aH or width > aW:
        style.fontSize -= 1
        lines = break_lines(text, aW)
        width, height = line_wrap(lines, style)


def renderPage(name, text):
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate("%s.pdf" % name)
    parts = []
    # Wasn't sure where PAGE_WIDTH and PAGE_HEIGHT came from for OP,
    # so I just used a standard A4 page measurement.
    PAGE_WIDTH, PAGE_HEIGHT = A4
    aW = PAGE_WIDTH - 4*inch  # available width and height 
    aH = PAGE_HEIGHT - 4*inch

    style = ParagraphStyle(name='fancy')
    style.fontSize = 200
    style.leading = 20
    shrink_font_size(aW, aH, text, style)

    p = Paragraph(text, style)
    parts.append(p)
    doc.build(parts)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    renderPage('test', '12345689019283382848248284 842828428529392381472754 842828428529392381472754 842828428529392381472754\n' * 10)
```

Comment: Thanks Nitzie. I'll give this a whirl and see how it goes. It strikes me that perhaps making a new Paragraph object and then wrap() -ing that might do the trick. Will let you know what I find. Seems an odd oversight of reportlab though.

Comment: @ThePiedPipes You could do that, for sure. You would probably have to do something similar to my answer in your calculation, as ReportLab uses `stringWidth` and `simpleSplit` in the `Paragraph` class too. But I think cleaning it up and using it in a custom class would be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Ah, unfortunately this didn't work quote as well as it needed to in my case. The reason is that once you set the leading, it's fixed. So I found that I had to also do the edit above to get it working. Thanks for the advice though. Top stuff.